# Why can't I use the same Icon for more than 1 item in Menu?

Tags: wpf, menu

I have a `MenuItem` like below

```
<MenuItem Header="Edit">
    <MenuItem Header="Copy Direct Link" Icon="{StaticResource CopyIcon}" Command="{Binding CopyImageCommand}" />
    <MenuItem Header="Copy Image Data" Icon="{StaticResource CopyIcon}" Command="{Binding CopyImageDataCommand}" />
    <MenuItem Header="Paste" Icon="{StaticResource PasteIcon}" Command="{Binding PasteImageCommand}" />
</MenuItem>
```

Notice the 1st 2 items use the same icon, I get something like below

[image]

I tried removing the 2nd item,

```
<MenuItem Header="Edit">
    <MenuItem Header="Copy Direct Link" InputGestureText="Ctrl+C" Icon="{StaticResource CopyIcon}" Command="{Binding CopyImageCommand}" />
    <!--<MenuItem Header="Copy Image Data" InputGestureText="Ctrl+Alt+C" Icon="{StaticResource CopyIcon}" Command="{Binding CopyImageDataCommand}" />-->
    <MenuItem Header="Paste" InputGestureText="Ctrl+P" Icon="{StaticResource PasteIcon}" Command="{Binding PasteImageCommand}" />
</MenuItem>
```

then I got something like

[image]

How can I reuse Icons?

Comment: This seems like an inherent issue. The same thing happens with vanilla WinForms. The solution there is to clone the image/menuitem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709228/wpf-disappaearing-icons) question

An Image can only have one parent so it will be moved from the first MenuItem to the second. You can add the x:Shared attribute like this

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Image x:Key="CopyIcon" x:Shared="False" Source="..." />
</Window.Resources>
```

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx)

> **x:Shared Attribute**
>   When set to false, modifies WPF
>   resource-retrieval behavior so that
>   requests for the attributed resource
>   create a new instance for each request
>   instead of sharing the same instance
>   for all requests.

Answer (score 5):

You're most likely declaring *CopyIcon* as Image type in your resource, something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <Image x:Key="CopyIcon" Source="yourcopyicon.ico"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

So, the root cause of the problem is, *Image* is a visual element, since it derives from *FrameworkElement* (which is a visual element), and **a visual element cannot have more than one parent at the same time**. That is why the first MenuItem is not showing the icon, since the second MenuItem **reset the parent** of CopyIcon, making itself parent of the CopyIcon.

Hope this explanation is helpful to you. Now follow what **Meleak** has said in his response. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<MenuItem Header=“Paste“ >
<MenuItem.Icon><Image Height=“16“ Width=“16“ Source=“paste.jpg“ /></MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```